# I want to insert text in html using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags, translators

I am a python developer and still learning, I want some help in scraping concept, I just want to tell you what I want. Below is the html code.
containig different tags like "em" , and p and span.

Classes are different , named as obisnuit and obisnuit2.

```
html1="""<p class="text_obisnuit2">Best 3 developers.</p>
        <p class="text_obisnuit">There are best three types of web developers in world.</p>
        <p class="text_obisnuit2"><em>A javascript web developer.</em></p>
        <p class="text_obisnuit"><em>A nodeJS web developer.</em></p>
        <p class="text_obisnuit"><em>A python web developer <span class="text_obisnuit2">Django developer</span></em></p>
"""
```

I am trying to translate text between them and and inserting a translated version of text and I am successful at this thing, but the issue is coming in tags.

Here is my code below: When I tried to scrape text using this method then the em tag was removed and only text was successfully inserted there.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import translators as ts
soup1=BeautifulSoup(html1, 'html.parser')

articles = soup1.find_all('p', {'class':"text_obisnuit"})
for a in articles:  

    original_text=a.text
    #print(original_text)
    translated_output=ts.google(original_text, from_language='en', to_language='ro')


    a.string = translated_output.lower()
    print(a.string)
```

After running the above method, the output was:

```
OUTPUT>>

<p class =" text_obisnuit2 "> Cei mai buni 3 dezvoltatori. </p>
<p class = "text_obisnuit"> Există cele mai bune trei tipuri de dezvoltatori web din lume. </p>
<p class = "text_obisnuit2"> Un dezvoltator web javascript. </p>
<p class = "text_obisnuit"> Un dezvoltator web nodeJS. </p>
<p class = "text_obisnuit"> Un dezvoltator web Python <span class = "text_obisnuit2"> Dezvoltator Django </span> </p>
```

If you see clearly, the em tag is removed from output, so I do not want it to be removed, I want the same html structure after translation.

I also tried this method but only the text of em tag was scraped, not the whole html text.

```
articles = soup1.find_all('em')
for item in articles:    
    original_text=item.text.strip()
    #print(original_text)
    translated_output=ts.google(original_text, from_language='en', to_language='ro')
    #print(item)

    item.string=translated_output
```

The OUTPUT I want should be:

```
OUTPUT>>

<p class =" text_obisnuit2 "> Cei mai buni 3 dezvoltatori. </p>
<p class = "text_obisnuit"> Există cele mai bune trei tipuri de dezvoltatori web din lume. </p>
<p class = "text_obisnuit2"><em> Un dezvoltator web javascript. </em></p>
<p class = "text_obisnuit"><em> Un dezvoltator web nodeJS. </em></p>
<p class = "text_obisnuit"><em> Un dezvoltator web Python <span class = "text_obisnuit2"> Dezvoltator Django </span></em> </p>
```

Anyone guide me, please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your html, the text elements are sometimes direct children of `<p>` and sometimes buried two or three layers below. Try this on your original html and see if it works:

```
for item in articles:
    targets = item.find_all()
    if len(targets)==0:        
        item.string=ts.google(item.string, from_language='en', to_language='ro')
    else:
      #EDIT: the next line was dropped: 
      for target in targets:
        if target.string:
            target.string=ts.google(target.string, from_language='en', to_language='ro')
```

Comment: This is what happened: "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'string'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: @MohammadIzaan Not sure what to tell you; this does work with the sample html in your question - so the sample may not be representative of your actual html.

Comment: It did not work, because I checked in the sample html instead of original one.

Comment: First error in your script was:  NameError: name 'target' is not defined

Comment: Then I changed it from target to targets. But the error was the one I sent you above.

Comment: I ran your script after removing string from target.string, but there is nothing difference, I received the same output that I received by this code of mine:                                                                         articles = soup1.find_all('em')
for item in articles:    
    original_text=item.text.strip()
    #print(original_text)
    translated_output=ts.google(original_text, from_language='en', to_language='ro')
    #print(item)

    item.string=translated_output

Comment: The concept of this question is, when I ran my both code which are stated above , then the one with obisnuit class overlapped on whole html and em tag got removed, only its text remained. So I want the same html with translated version.

Comment: I checked again and there was a typo in the copy and paste in the answer; try the edit and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I need a whole return html page

Comment: You are just scraping and translating, But I need the code that will be used to returning whole html with translated version without removing of child tag <em>